# Checkbox won't change value with javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have 2 check boxes where only one or none may be checked.
Since I can't do a postback I tried this with Javascript.
The Javascript finds the element (tested it with an alert).
But the value won't change.

Any Idea how I can do this with Javascript?

The Javascript:

```
function mrcAndNbbFilterChanged(mrcOrNbb)
        {
            alert("er in");
          if(mrcOrNbb == 0)
          { 
            document.getElementById("ctl00_contentHolder_cb_mrcFilter").checked=true; 
            document.getElementById("ctl00_contentHolder_cbNoBackBilling").checked=false; 
            alert(document.getElementById("ctl00_contentHolder_cbNoBackBilling"));
            alert("0");
          }
          else
          {
            if(mrcOrNbb == 1)
            {
                alert("1");
                document.getElementById("cb_mrcFilter").checked=false; 
                document.getElementById("cbNoBackBilling").checked=true; 
            }
          }
        }
```

The ASP code:

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="cb_mrcFilter" runat="server" Text="Only MRC" OnClick="mrcAndNbbFilterChanged(0)" /> 
<asp:CheckBox ID="cbNoBackBilling" runat="server" Text="No back billing" OnClick="mrcAndNbbFilterChanged(1)"  />
```

Comment: This should work. Can you create a fiddle to replicate?

Comment: why not just use the checkbox list (or radio button list my be better as that limits the user to only having one selected), also is there a reason you can't do a post back?

Comment: @ØHankyPankyØ I'll try to do this. But I won't be surprised if it works in Fiddle

Comment: @jgok222 Checkbox list could be an option. Doesn't need a radio button always need one value to be selected? (it also looks different).
There will be functions running when I do a postback, this is why I can't do this.

Comment: as @JamesDonnolly pointed, you should check the HTML code generated by ASP, to be sure that you are using the correct ID ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ASP.NET applies that `ctl00_`-esque string to IDs when using ASP controls to ensure they are unique. You can get the ASP-modified ID value using:

```
document.getElementById("<%= cb_mrcFilter.ClientID %>").checked=false;
document.getElementById("<%= cbNoBackBilling.ClientID %>").checked=true;
```

Also, as a side note, you can use `else if { ... }`, rather than `else { if { ... } }` when only dealing with one alternative:

```
if(mrcOrNbb == 0) {
    ...
}
else if(mrcOrNbb == 1) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: +1 for the `else if` advice, but I'm wondering if an `else` would be enough on this case ;)

Comment: It was indeed the id, Thanks!